# Twitter Stream API Corrupted Data

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

I am trying to track some keywords with the [LinqToTwitter](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) library. When I look at the buffer, the data format is not correct.

For example, the data should look like:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Jul 31 04:21:25 +0000 2014","id":494699327386693632,"id_str":"494699327386693632" ...... ,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"tr"}
```

But the data looks like:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Jul 31 04:21:25 +0000 2014","id":494699327386693632,"id_str":"494699327386693632" ...... ,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"tr"} JCAAIMhJz.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/Bt18rBJCAAIMhJz.jpg"
```

Sample code like that (little bit different from linqtotwitter default example):

```
        await
            (from strm in TwitterCtx.Streaming
             where strm.Type == StreamingType.Filter &&
                 strm.Track == Track
             select strm)
            .StartAsync(async strm =>
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strm.Content))
                    buffer += strm.Content;
                else
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(buffer))
                    {
                        streamContentList.Add(buffer);
                        buffer = String.Empty;
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                if (count >= QueryBoundary)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { mongoAnalyzeUpdateQueryMethod(MongoDB, MongoKeyName, (long)count); });

                    count = 0;
                    streamContentList = new List<string>();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            });
```

I think I broke the data order when I tried to control content. 
What should I do resolve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem fixed in the latest version on LINQ to Twitter, v3.0.4. [1]

[1] https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/discussions/542281